# Defining path tree in Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, gulp

Ive got a Node.js application with Gulp that has a deep directory structure up to about 5 levels.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a better way to define the paths for the Gulp build. So I started doing the following,

```
var path = require('path'),

    _joinPaths = function (parent, subPath) {
        return parent.dir ? path.join(parent.dir, subPath) : subPath;
    },

    _subPath = function (parent, propName, subPath) {
        subPath = subPath || propName;
        parent[propName] = {
            dir: _joinPaths(parent, subPath)
        };
    },

    _entryPath = function (parent, entryPath) {
        parent.entry = _joinPaths(parent, entryPath);
    },

    _pathPattern = function (parent, includes, excludes) {
    };

function Paths() {
    var paths = {};

    _subPath(paths, 'src', './');
    _subPath(paths.src, 'lib');

    // Define more paths
};
```

So in the end i can access the paths as `paths.src.lib` for example.

However, this looks way too cumbersome. There has to be a better way to achieve the same thing.

Can someone give any advice around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES2015 features for this

**Proxy**:

```
const proxyPath = require('../');

var tmp = proxyPath('/tmp');

console.log(tmp.cache['project-1']['..'].files + ''); // /tmp/cache/files
```

Proxy code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = structure;

const cache = new Map();

function structure(root) {
    var dir = path.resolve(root);
    var dirs;

    if (! cache.has(dir)) {
        if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            dirs = fs.readdirSync(dir + '');
        } else {
            dirs = [];
        }
        cache.set(dir, dirs);
    } else {
        dirs = cache.get(dir);
    }

    function toString() {
        return dir;
    }

    return new Proxy({}, {
        has(target, prop) {
            return dirs.indexOf(prop) > -1;
        },
        ownKeys(target) {
            return [...dirs];
        },
        get(target, prop) {
            switch (prop) {
                case Symbol.toPrimitive:
                case 'toString':
                case 'valueOf':
                    return toString;
                    break;
                default:
                if (typeof prop === 'string') {
                    return structure(path.resolve(dir, prop));
                } else {
                    return dir[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Class** inherited from Array [as npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dir-array):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const DIR = Symbol('DirectoryArray.Dir');

class DirectoryArray extends Array {
    // Load directory structure if it exists
    constructor(dir) {
        super();

        this[DIR] = path.resolve(dir);

        if (fs.existsSync(this[DIR])) {
            this.push(...fs.readdirSync(this[DIR]));
        }
    }

    // Create Directory array from relative path
    // supports '..' for lookup
    dir(dir) {
        return new this.constructor(
            path.resolve(
                this[DIR], dir
            )
        );
    }

    toString() {
        return this[DIR];
    }
}

DirectoryArray.Dir = DIR;


// Usage example

var cwd = new DirectoryArray(process.cwd());
var test = cwd.dir('test');

console.log(cwd + '');
console.log(cwd.join(', '));
console.log(test + '');
console.log(test.join(', '));
```